# Search the correct data with the correct date and print it in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the question.

```
ID        Name         Price         Date
1         Nike         USD3          23/5/2013
2         Polo         USD13         23/5/2013
3         Nike         USD2          4/6/2013
4         Nike         USD50         23/5/2013
5         Adidas       USD30         5/6/2013
```

Above data are save in the excel. How do I get the Nike details with the dates 23/5/2013 and show it into new sheets in excel. Thanks for you all helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search the correct data and print it in excel vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311809/search-the-correct-data-and-print-it-in-excel-vba)

Comment: you have asked almost the same question. There is not important difference between the two, so, I'll suggest to close one...

Comment: That post close already. The question that I want to ask is this. Sorry for making you confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could filter it by the date column using Autofilter then copy those records to your destination sheet.

maybe like this:

```
Dim xSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim xSheet2 As Worksheet
Dim iLastRow As Integer

Set xSheet1 = Sheets("sheet1")
Set xSheet2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

iLastRow = xSheet1.Range("A" & xSheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

xSheet2.Cells.Clear
Range("F1").Value = "check"
Range("F2:F" & iLastRow).Formula = "=IF(AND(B:B=""Nike"",TEXT(D:D,""DD/MM/YYYY"")=""23/05/2013""),1,0)"

Range("F1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"

Range("A2:D" & iLastRow).Copy

xSheet2.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, SkipBlanks:=True

With xSheet1
    .Range("F1").AutoFilter
    .Range("F1:F" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).Clear
End With
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much Philip on your help.

Comment: @user1928481 If the answer was what you are looking for please mark it as an answer